# What does & at the end of a linux command & have to do with signals?

Tags: linux

From bash, i run a python script, which in turn, starts a C++ program. Inside the C++ program is a signal handler. Now, when i start the script like this - python3 myscript.py - ,  everything works fine. When i add & to the end - python3 myscript.py & - the signal handler is triggered.(SIG_DFL). Now, from what i understand, & at the end of a bash command, puts the command in background, and gives control to the bash script/terminal. What does this have to do with triggering the signal handler/ sending SIG_DFL signal?

Comment: What signal is the signal handler assigned to?

Comment: If a background process tries to read from the terminal it gets a `SIGTTIN` signal.

Comment: The default action for SIGTTIN is to suspend the process. When you move the process into the foreground it will be able to read from the terminal.

Comment: You can disable this with `stty -tostop`. But then you can get unpredictable behavior, because you can't tell whether a particular input will go to the shell or the program.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `SIG_DFL`. The default action for any signal isn't to run a handler function.

Comment: The handler is assigned to SIGINT.

Comment: The default action of `SIGINT` is to terminate the process, not run a handler that you establish.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why running the program in the background would send the SIGINT signal.

Comment: You're going to have to post a [mre] that shows what you mean.